# Azure storage blob - ConditionNotMet

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I've tried to download blob from azure storage (az cli), but I've got this. Could someone know how to solve it?

```
ErrorCode: ConditionNotMet
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ConditionNotMet</Code><Message>The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
RequestId:8nnpca91-201e-011p-7n9e-b1a77b000900
Time:2020-11-23T11:48:11.4500961Z</Message></Error>
```

Comment: what does your command look like?

Comment: Could you please provide your script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue without knowing the exact command you're trying to run, but here is the basic syntax of the [az storage blob download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_download) command with an example that works:

```
az storage blob download --container-name <storage-account-container-name> --file <file-path-to-write-out-to> --name <blob-name> --account-name <storage-account-name> --account-key <storage-account-access-key>
```

Example:

```
$ az storage blob download --container-name testbkp --file backup1.log --name backup1.log --account-name myStorageAccount --account-key r+nHfm5ZZxf9r4TueZ7bmkVFwO8cBi+wmq/9g==

Finished[#############################################################]  100.0000%
{
  "content": null,
  "deleted": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "name": "backup1.log",
  "properties": {
    "appendBlobCommittedBlockCount": null,
    "blobTier": null,
    "blobTierChangeTime": null,
    "blobTierInferred": false,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "contentLength": 503,
    "contentRange": "bytes 0-502/503",
    "contentSettings": {
      "cacheControl": null,
      "contentDisposition": null,
      "contentEncoding": null,
      "contentLanguage": null,
      "contentMd5": "b8Lzmr+LfkdoZaPujOqVlg==",
      "contentType": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    "copy": {
      "completionTime": null,
      "id": null,
      "progress": null,
      "source": null,
      "status": null,
      "statusDescription": null
    },
    "creationTime": "2020-10-11T16:23:35+00:00",
    "deletedTime": null,
    "etag": "\"0x8D86E0100F405DC\"",
    "lastModified": "2020-10-11T16:23:35+00:00",
    "lease": {
      "duration": null,
      "state": "available",
      "status": "unlocked"
    },
    "pageBlobSequenceNumber": null,
    "remainingRetentionDays": null,
    "serverEncrypted": true
  },
  "snapshot": null
}
```

Note that the parameter names you pass to the account are case-sensitive. If you still run into issues despite being on the latest version of Azure CLI (**2.15.1** as of today), you could give it a try from [Azure Cloud Shell](https://shell.azure.com/bash) as well.

Comment: Thank u so much, I found another solution to download azure blobs. By using Azure UI